# JDBC driver for Google BigQuery?

Tags: java, google-bigquery

Does anyone know of any JDBC interface or driver for Google BigQuery?

Only Java please - I'm done with the Python library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a google supported JDBC driver for BigQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34443600/is-there-a-google-supported-jdbc-driver-for-bigquery)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE**: this post was made in 2012, since then Google has a fully compliant JDBC driver here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/odbc-jdbc-drivers

There is a 3rd party JDBC driver, which can be obtained from:

http://code.google.com/p/starschema-bigquery-jdbc/

It supports the same SQL SELECT syntax as the original Google BigQuery, and there is no insert or update support. Please let me know if you have any further questions or requests about the driver

Comment: Thanks, looks promising I will try this out. I hope it will integrates with our visualization frontend

Comment: That driver was last updated in 2013.  I think the project is defunct.

Answer (score 4):

Google now offers one that is freely avaliable that was developed by one of their partners: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/partners/simba-drivers/#current_jdbc_driver_releases

Answer (score -1):

There is also 3rd party [Simba Drivers for BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/partners/simba-drivers/):

> Google has partnered with Simba Technologies Inc, a Magnitude Software Company to provide ODBC and JDBC drivers that leverage the power of BigQuery's Standard SQL.
>
> The intent of these drivers is to help users connect the power of Google BigQuery with existing tooling and infrastructure that does not have native integration. If you are building new integrations with BigQuery, we recommend you consider the native API. The functionality exposed by an ODBC/JDBC connection is necessarily a subset of the full capabilities of BigQuery.

Comment: This is a duplicate of the earlier answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40442073/543738

Answer (score -2):

There is no JDBC driver as far as I know but there is a Java API that could help:
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/

Comment: This is outdated.