# Is there a google supported JDBC driver for BigQuery?

Tags: jdbc, google-bigquery, star-schema

We are looking to access BigQuery through third party sql clients, ex. RazorSql. I came across StarSchema JDBC driver and I could not make it work with Razorsql and on the webpage it says that the project was archived. So, not sure if its supposed to work. Any suggestions?

The error I get when trying to use it with RazoeSql is:

```
java.io.IOException: toDerInputStream rejects tag type 123
```

I am using a service account key file for authentication.

This is JDBC url value I use (where "my-poc" is the project id and "MY_POC" is the dataset name):

```
jdbc:BQDriver:my-poc%3AMY_POC?withServiceAccount=true
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jdbc driver for google bigquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213339/jdbc-driver-for-google-bigquery)

Answer (score 3):

Alas, no there isn't a JDBC driver that is officially supported. There is an ODBC driver developed by Simba in conjunction with google (you can download it [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/third-party-tools) for free), and you can use a JDBC to ODBC bridge (although the official one is deprecated in java 8, I believe you can download one from a couple of different folks ([here](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/jdbc_odbc_bridge/#section=tab-1), for example).

Admittedly, this is not a great solution. IMO Google really *should* provide a JDBC driver, but they do not.

Comment: Simbra in partnership with Google seems to have recently released a JDBC driver as well: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/partners/simba-drivers/#current_jdbc_driver_releases

Answer (score 0):

> java.io.IOException: toDerInputStream rejects tag type 123

The JDBC driver requires a p12 formatted file instead of the json formatted file.